# php gettext fails loading html tag

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

I'm using gettext to translate my website. One key has a translations with a html tag:

```
msgid "BANNER_TAG_START"
msgstr "<!-- // MY BANNER TAG -->"
```

if I use this code in php now:

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars(gettext('BANNER_TAG_START')));
```

it normally should returns:

```
<!-- // MY BANNER TAG -->
```

most times it works like this, but sometimes I get:

```
MY BANNER TAG
```

Why do I sometimes get this wrong code?

Comment: Can you narrow down "sometimes"? When does what happens? A randomly different output on each page load is implausible.

Comment: if I reload the same page 100 times, I get it about 3 to 5 times... but it is always the same site. same parameters and so on. really strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my env, running the following code,

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars("<!-- // MY BANNER TAG -->"));
```

returns this,

```
string(31) "&lt;!-- // MY BANNER TAG --&gt;"
```

not

```
<!-- // MY BANNER TAG -->
```

as you reported. So I assume you are reporting the final rendered text on your browser, instead of the generated HTML source code.

Please check the 3-5 in 100 times where the problem happen in the generated HTML source code, and check if the what kind of other letters or line-breaks exist BEFORE the "<!-- //", then you may find the difference for the 3-5 cases.